# How do I install Windows Phone 8 on HTC One M8?

Tags: 8.0

I have an HTC One M8 that is currently running Android. With the announcement of the [HTC One M8 for Windows](http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones/htc-one-m8-windows/?PS=1&cid=sem157p6229814%7Bnetwork%7D-c) I know that my phone can support Windows Phone 8. How do I install Windows Phone 8 on my device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently impossible to install Windows Phone 8 on an HTC One M8 running Android. You'll have to buy an HTC One M8 with Windows Phone 8 pre-installed.

Comment: Why is this impossible?  It's the exact same hardware.  Is it proprietary to HTC?

Comment: Maybe you'll be able to do it in the future. Maybe HTC will help you or someone over at XDA will help you. But, currently, there is no way of doing it.